# Docker Port 8000 bind address already in use after Docker update

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm just picked up a project again which I worked on a few month ago. Tbh, it is my first experience with docker. It went well at the beginning but after update docker from version 4.08.xxxx to v 4.11.1 (84025) yesterday I'm running into problems today. These problems only started after turning on the PC today.
When running docker-compose up --build one service can't be started because port 8000 is blocked by a other service on my host machine as seen below.

```
Cannot start service backend: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint admin_backend_1 (846b1b7447d5108e41ca67307eaa65fae143dc2c005fffe7b8c9da476c3b60e1): listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8000: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project
```

Running netstat -a -b -o reveals no service listening to 0.0.0.0:8000 as shown in the picture attached.

What I have already tried:

1. Using netstat to find which service is listening to this address
2. docker-compose down on all containers
3. Restarting computer, of course
4. Changing port 8000:8000 to 8003:8000 in docker-compose.yml (Works but only fights the symptom not the cause...)

Does somebody know, why this just started to occur and how I can solve it?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'


services: 
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db


  queue:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python consumer.py'
    depends_on:
      - db


  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.38
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
```

[image: netstat result]

Comment: Wait, you **do** have a process listening on `127.0.0.1:8000`, 3rd line from the end on the picture (although I don't know what does HERGESTELLT mean), no? You need to stop it first. You cannot bind to 0.0.0.0 when 127.0.0.1 corresponding port is in use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. As axplained in my other comment to kevin mugwe I already tried killing all services occupying this port but with no success... But these services must have been running all the time before too

Comment: Just choose any other port, if 8000 is occupied - bind 8000 of container to 8001 of host, like `ports: -127.0.0.1:8001:8000`.

Comment: Yes thats what I did to fix it. I was just curious to find out why it just happened with port 8000 ..
Many thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Check this out ... Port 8000 is already in use
[image]

Comment: I was already looking into these services but I was not Bale to get the port free. If I kill the RzSDKServer.exe this port gets occupied by asus_framework.exe. After killing that, RzSDKServer comes back. These are services for my mouse and my Mainboard. If those are making problems why didn't I run into it month before? Is there maybe a option I can toggle somewhere to give docker priority?

Comment: Judging by their behavior, those sound like malware.  Mouse drivers should never have a need to reach the Internet unless it's phoning home with whatever it is you're doing with the mouse.  Same with a mainboard component.  I'd strongly recommend looking further into those processes.